# analysis scale barcode label to multi textbox vb net 2013

Tags: vb.net

i have retail program i want to add scale into my system by analysis bar-code for example if scanned bar-code start with 92 that mean this label generated by the scale 
and i need  5 number after 92 to be item bar-code and 5 number to read weight from scale and last number it's check number
/ another example if scanned bar-code is 92-11111-05122-2 
***** 92 its check number if this scale or not 
***** if yes 11111 this item id and it price and name come from database
****** 05122 its weight /1000 to get weight per kilo
****** 2 its check no need to use it 
***** i need weight in quantity text-box

any advise 
********* sorry for my language *********

Comment: I need a winning lottery ticket, do you have one? Don't tell us what you need, show us an attempt at solving the problem and ask for help if what you tried doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this solution :
      `Dim scode As String = barcode.Text.ToString
        If (((scode.Length = 13) AndAlso scode.StartsWith("92"))) Then
            Dim weight As Double = 0
            'here to get item barcode
            Dim getitembarcode As String = scode.Substring(2, 5)
'here to get item barcode
            Dim getweight As String = scode.Substring(7, 5)`

```
        'to add weight per kilo
        weight = (Double.Parse(getweight) / 1000)
        qty.Text = weight
        item_barcode.Text = getitembarcode

    Else

    End If
```

`
thanks